# WCF HTTPS certificate implementation questions

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, ssl

When implementing an SSL secured web service with WCF, does the WCF Service require a certificate?  Also need to know if the client need to pass the certificate for authentication in order to call an HTTPS enabled WCF service.

I am looking for guidance on designing a secure WCF service where all data will be passed between service and wcf client in a very secure encrypted way, with or without using ssl & certificate. Please advise regarding the available mechanisms to secure the communicate between service & client. discuss all the possibilities. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF Services that expose https (SSL) bindings need to have a Service certificate.

Web Service clients do not need certificates unless you are attempting to use mutual authentication.

The following link provides a step by step overview of configuring an IIS-hosted WCF service with SSL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx

In the event that you do not want to use certificates, the following may help:
[WCF message security without certificate and windows auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570939/wcf-message-security-without-certificate-and-windows-auth)

Comment: i heard that when we use certificate with wcf service then client also need to install certificate which i do not want. i want my wcf service will use https and certificate but the whoever client will consume our service they will not require to install & pass certificate. so guide me how to do it. thanks

Comment: what is mutual authentication in wcf ?

Comment: The following seems to provide the information you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870677/using-wcf-ssl-certificate-over-tcp-without-client-certificate-server-side-only